# does lubuntu use ubuntu package repository?

Tags: ubuntu

Does Lubuntu 12.10 use Ubuntu 12.10 prebuilt binary package repository or does it have its own??

I like a light-weight distro, but huge selection of packages is even more important for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<del>Google</del> [DuckDuckGo](http://www.duckduckgo.com) is your friend :)

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu#Lubuntu_VS_Ubuntu (emphasis mine):

> Lubuntu VS Ubuntu
>
> Both Lubuntu and Ubuntu share Two Major Important Things:
>
> - Same Core System
> - **Same Repositories**
>
> Lubuntu and Ubuntu belong to the same family and talking about each as
>   totally different two systems is not correct since they have some
>   things in common. Thus, we use the same Forum Area and share many Wiki
>   Pages.
>
> The differences between Lubuntu and Ubuntu are:
>
> - Different DE - Lubuntu uses LXDE while Ubuntu uses Unity as the default DE.
> - Different Default Applications
>
> Other than that, they are the same. The DE is what makes Lubuntu a
>   lightweight OS, and of course the selected applications too because we
>   make sure to use the lightest applications which are not resource
>   hungry.

Also, as a general rule, if you want a *lightweight* distro don't go for Ubuntu. Any flavor. Go for a real light weight distro like [damnsmalllinux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/), or [Arch](https://www.archlinux.org/).